# Show that a multivariable function isn't injective anywhere

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^d), n>d $
>
> Show that $f$ isn't injective in a neighborhood of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall x$

I thought about assuming there is such $x$ and thus a sphere $U=B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ where $f$ is injective, and then looking at $f:U \to f(U)$ which is invertible, trying to get to a contradiction somehow, but with no success so far.
Hints appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean $n > d$? Otherwise you can take the embedding $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I think you mean $n>d$. The function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x)=(x,x)$ is certainly injective.

Comment: Thank you, fixed

Comment: What tools do you have to use? The fact that $f$ need not have constant rank causes difficulties and makes this harder, I believe. But you can at least start by looking at (near) a point $x$ where the rank of $f$ is maximal.

Comment: @TedShifrin mostly implicit/invertible function theorem here I would assume

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed. So if the map has rank $d$ everywhere, you know how to do it. You can modify that argument if it has constant rank. But the general question is quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it was injective in some open ball. By reducing the radius, we can assume it is continuous in a closed ball. Let $B$ be this ball.

We now restrict $f$ to $B$. Then we have a bijection $B \to f(B)$. This is a surjection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, so it is a quotient map (it maps open sets to open sets). Hence, $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $f(B)$, so $f$ restricted to $B$ is a homeomorphism.

Note that $f(B)$ is compact and connected. Then, it is connected and bounded, so it is homeomorphic to a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to a ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ if $n \neq d$.

Comment: Invariance of domain is well out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a calculus/analysis proof, I believe yours relies on topology?

Comment: Algebraic topology, in fact.

Comment: @paxtibimarce I am afraid it does. I should have read the tags, sorry.